# Difference of water pressure

Tags: pressure, water, statics, fluid-statics

We know that $P = \rho gh$, so is it true that water pressure at 2nd floor will be higher than water pressure at 9th floor of a 12 story building?

Comment: You have expression with you, you can calculate the same taking two explicit numbers for 2nd floor height and 9th floor height. Say 20m and 90m respectively.
Btw the answer is ```YES```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES. But just to make things clear:

- Here, ***h*** means the height of water surface from the point you are measuring pressure. So, if you have some water jars in your room on 2nd and 9th floor, this equation does not involve. But if you fill the whole 12 storied building with water, only then you can measure the water pressure on 2nd and 9th floor with this equation. And YES, water pressure on 2nd floor will be higher than the pressure on 9th floor.
- And yet if it is not trivial to you, you can think this way- there are 3 floors of water above 9th floor. If every floor contains ***m*** kg of water, then those 3 floors will contain ***3m*** kg of water and 10 floors above 2nd floor will contain ***10m*** kg of water. And, obviously, ***10m*** kg water will exert more pressure than ***3m*** kg.

Comment: it was very helpful for me let me make it little bit clear the question is related with normal water supply for the floors that is supplied in building